# Как поменять все прописные на строчные с подчеркиванием?

Tags: c#

Есть строка, в которой нужно заменить все идентификаторы вида

```
SomeIdentifier
```

на идентификаторы вида

```
some_identifier
```

Готовое решение (работает правильно):

```
string GetUnderScore(string source)
{
    string target = "";

    foreach (char c in source)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(c))
        {
            target += "_" + char.ToLower(c);
        }
        else
        {
            target += c;
        }
    }
    if (target[0] == '_')
    {
        target = target.Substring(1);
    }

    return target;
}
```

но уж как-то много кода для такой простой задачи. Как упростить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно избавиться от `else` и второго `if` и если строки длинные, то лучше использовать `StringBuilder` вместо `string`, т.к. `StringBuilder` не создаёт новую строку с копированием символов из предыдущей при каждом добавлении наших `char` :)

```
    string GetUnderScore(string source) {
        var result = new StringBuilder(source);
        foreach (char c in source) {
            if (char.IsUpper(c) && result.Length > 0)
                result.Append("_");
            result.Append(char.ToLower(c));
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте регулярные выражения, они созданы специально для таких задач:

```
string GetUnderScore(string source)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?!^)(?=[A-Z])");

    return pattern.Replace(source, "_").ToLower();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Большое количество кода не всегда плохо. Эта функция довольно коротка. Важнее его доступность для поддержки и эффективность. Эффективность будет, если помнить, что строки - это неизменяемые объекты (immutable), каждый оператор  += это создание нового объекта, поэтому необходимо использовать StringBuilder. SubString  в конце не нужен, просто надо отдельно в начале обрабатывать первую букву, а цикл начинать с 1.